# Meteor: How to place template content below video background header

Tags: html, video, meteor

I've got a video background where normally a carousel would be. I'm still learning the complexities of CSS, and I'm a little confused about whether or not I can position the contents of my templates below the video using Meteor. I'm thinking it may be better to load the template below the video, so that the video plays consistently in the layout header, but my routes can change underneath it. Basically, what I'm trying to do is make all my routes appear underneath the html5 video header. Please help Wizards.

the video is it's own template in layout.html --> {{> video}}

the "Heading" elements are part of my "home" template.

[image]

Comment: You should only need `margin-top: 600px` in the style of your first content div (for example), or whatever the height of the video is. Many ways to solve this. Normally if you put something in the background then it's your intent to have content overlay it.

Comment: Now when I resize the screen the "Heading" divs end up way down the page. Is there any other way to make the content show up exclusively below the video?

Comment: By _first div_ I mean the first div you want to push down. Not the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is purely CSS, meteor doesn't control your styles. There are many possible solutions, but why not just wrap the video in a div and give it a specific height & 100% width. As long as it's before your your header, it will push the rest of the content beneath it.

**CSS**

```
.video { 
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

**Templates**

```
<div class="video">
  {{> video}}
</div>

  {{> header}}
  {{> otherTemplates}}
```